# Recaptcha Ideal Solution for Client-Side Validation

Tags: c#, jquery, recaptcha

Recaptcha:
i want to use recaptcha for the login page of my site which is built on jQuery and ASP.net. Before posting this question i googled about the recaptcha and studied about that...
use the recaptcha with ASP.NET which was doing server side validation where i needed to include the dll for the [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) and using it as a server control and then validating it using isValid property of the page.

What I want is client side validation for the recaptcha using jquery, how should i do this?

is there any good tutorial to do that or ideal solution?

Comment: The problem with client-side validation is that the user can turn it off, and a bot probably won't even run it anyway...

Comment: good to read http://bit.ly/1hsTyyz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in client-side. You cannot do it without the help of your server, since the recaptcha is owned by google (its not your domain), you cannot directly make a request to verify it though.

Due to security reasons cross domain XMLHttpRequests  is prohibited. You can alternatively make an AJAX call to your server when the recaptcha is been filled out(`onblur` of the `recaptcha_response_field`) and validate it.

Comment: Can u elaborate how to do that ??

like this:

$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'WebMethod',
    data: JSON.stringify(captchaInfo),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg)
    {
        alert(msg.d); // Either true o false, true indicates CAPTCHA is validated successfully.
    }
});

Comment: See if this would help you - http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX

Answer (score 2):

Why in the world would you want to process captcha on the client side? Probably you'll hook something inside your form submission function like this:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){
    // other validation
    if(reCaptchaValidated()==false){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Can you prevent someone from doing this:

```
$('#form1').unbind("submit").submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution

Add reference to google ajax recapcha and generate the capcha.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showRecaptcha() {
     Recaptcha.create("6LfLrusSAAAAAIoi3XkbGvm2fLao3VjsNTjRoK-K", 'captchadiv', {
                            tabindex: 1,
                            theme: "white",
                            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
     });
  }
  window.onload = function () { showRecaptcha(); }
</script>
```

HTML entry

```
<form id="myform">
   <div id="captchadiv">
    </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Create a Javascript call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('myform').submit(function() {

     $.getJSON("someurl/api/ValidateRecapcha", param).done(function (ret) {
                   if(ret) alert('recacha matched');
                   else alert('mismatched');
     })
})
</script>
```

Im using ASP.net Webapi for the service and downloaded the Recaptcha.dll from here. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet

```
[HttpGet]
public bool ValidateRecapcha(string challengetKey, string input)
{
   var r = new Recaptcha.RecaptchaValidator();
   r.PrivateKey = "Recapcha Private Key"
   r.Challenge = challengetKey;
   r.Response = input;
   r.RemoteIP = "REMOTE_ADDR".ToServerVariables();
   var response = r.Validate();
   return response.IsValid;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check out [QapTcha : jQuery captcha system with jQuery & jQuery UI](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/QapTcha) or [AJAX FANCY CAPTCHA - JQUERY PLUGIN](http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin)

Used it before and it worked great for me..

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you show what you have already but I did find this that might be something like what your looking for.

[Validating Recaptcha using client side call](http://weblogs.asp.net/bilalshouman/archive/2009/05/06/validating-recaptcha-using-client-side-web-service-calls.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using google's reCaptcha (Yes it's server side) becuase client can always turn on client side Captcha.

But anyway here is 8 Cpatchas using jQuery, including tutorials.

[8 jQuery CAPTCHA Plugin with Tutorial](http://visionwidget.com/tuts/webtuts/591-jquery-captcha-plugin-with-tutorial.html)

Hope it help :)